# How to add sub-subdomain at Nginx?

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, subdomain

I'm trying configure a sub-subdomain on Nginx running on Ubuntu. I already have a configuration to access `http://staging.mydomain.com` and it works fine but now I need to access this URL `http://api.staging.mydomain.com`.

I tried this but without success:

```
upstream myapp {
    server unix:/var/tmp/myapp.sock;
}

upstream myapp_api {
    server unix:/var/tmp/myapp_api.sock;
}

# Configuration to subdomain
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    server_name staging.mydomain.com;

    location / {
        root /var/www/myapp/current/public;

        if (!-f $request_filename) {
            proxy_pass http://myapp;
            break;
        }
    }
}

# Configuration to sub-subdomain
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name api.staging.mydomain.com;

    location / {
        root /var/www/api_myapp/current/public;

        if (!-f $request_filename) {
            proxy_pass http://api_myapp;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

With this configuration I received this error:

```
The server at api.staging.mydomain.com can't be found, because the DNS lookup failed.
```

Any ideas?
Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

> The server at api.staging.example.com can't be found, because the DNS
>   lookup failed.

You need to create a DNS `CNAME` or `A` record for this.